Nginx not working Properly with Socket.io as LoadBalancer
I have a working socket.io application with Nodejs using Apache-Kafka. Now I want to scale my socket.io and for that purpose I created multiple instance of my socketservice.js.  I created three files server1.js server2.js server3.js they all have same code with different Port. Now I wanted to use Nginx as LoadBalancer such that when a user connects firstly it connects to the server1 and then if other user comes it get connected to server2 and same for server3.
Here is my nginx.conf
events {}
http {
    upstream socket_services {
        server localhost:4001;
        server localhost:4002;
        server localhost:4003;
    }

    upstream fetch_service {
        server localhost:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;

        location /api/chat/ {
            proxy_pass http://fetch_service;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://socket_services;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
    }
}



and my socketservice.js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { kafka, producer, getConsumer } = require('./controllers/healsynckafka');
const createSocketServer = require('./controllers/socketserver');
const GroupChatMessage = require("./dbSchema/GroupChatMessage");
const OneOnOneChatMessage = require("./dbSchema/OneOnOneChatMessage");
const RoomChatMessage = require("./dbSchema/RoomMessages");
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

const { server, io } = createSocketServer(app);

const runConsumer = async () => {
const consumer = await getConsumer('healsync');
await consumer.connect();
await consumer.subscribe({ topic: 'Messages' });

await consumer.run({
    eachMessage: async ({ topic, partition, message }) => {
        const { key, value } = message;
        const parsedMessage = JSON.parse(value.toString());
        if (key) {
            const timestamp = parseInt(key.toString());
            if(parsedMessage.room){
                const roomMessage = new RoomChatMessage({
                    room: parsedMessage.room,
                    sender: parsedMessage.sender,
                    content: parsedMessage.content,
                    createdAt: new Date(timestamp),
                });
                try {
                    io.to(room).emit("roommessage", roomMessage);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error saving room message:', error.message);
                }
            }
            else if (parsedMessage.receiverId) {
                const oneOnOneMessage = new OneOnOneChatMessage({
                    senderId: parsedMessage.senderId,
                    receiverId: parsedMessage.receiverId,
                    content: parsedMessage.content,
                    createdAt: new Date(timestamp),
                });
                try {
                    const receiverSocket = users[parsedMessage.receiverId];
                    if (receiverSocket) {
                        receiverSocket.emit('privateMessage', oneOnOneMessage);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Receiver is not online or invalid.');
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error saving one-on-one message:', error.message);
                }
            } else {
                const groupChatMessage = new GroupChatMessage({
                    senderId: parsedMessage.senderId,
                    content: parsedMessage.content,
                    createdAt: new Date(timestamp),
                });
                try {
                   
                    io.emit('message', groupChatMessage);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error saving group chat message:', error.message);
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Message key not found.');
        }
    },
});
};

const runProducer = async () => {
  await producer.connect();
};

const sendMessage = async (key, message) => {
try {
    await producer.send({
        topic: 'Messages',
        messages: [{ key: key.toString(), value: JSON.stringify(message) }],
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error sending message:', error.message);
}
};

runConsumer().catch(console.error);
runProducer().catch(console.error);



const users = {};
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New user connected ->', socket.id, ' on PORT --> username', PORT);
    socket.on('setUsername', (username) => {
        users[username] = socket;
        console.log(`Username set for ${socket.id}: ${username}`);
    });

    socket.on("fetchMessages", async (room) => {
        try {
          const messages = await RoomChatMessage.find({ room }).sort({ createdAt: 1 }).exec();
          socket.emit("fetchedMessages", messages);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Error fetching messages:", err);
        }
    });

    socket.on('message', async (data) => {
      const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const message = new GroupChatMessage({
            senderId: data.senderId,
            content: data.content,
        });
        await sendMessage(timestamp, message);
    });

    socket.on("joinRoom", async ({ room, sender }) => {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on("roommessage", async (data) => {
        const { room, sender, content } = data;
        console.log("server roommessage event on - ",room,sender,content)
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime();


        const newMessage = new RoomChatMessage({
            room: room,
            sender: sender,
            content: content
        })

        await sendMessage(timestamp , newMessage)

        
        console.log("sended to roomsg event");
    });
    socket.on("leaveRoom", (roomName) => {
    socket.leave(roomName);
    });
    socket.on('privateMessage', async (data) => {
      const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const { username, content, senderId } = data;
        const message = new OneOnOneChatMessage({
            senderId: senderId,
            receiverId: username,
            content: content
        });
        await sendMessage(timestamp,message);
        
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('User disconnected');
        delete users[socket.id];
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});


my client.jsx is
useEffect(() => {

    if(localStorage.getItem('username') === null){

      window.location.href = "/";
    } 
    const newSocket = io(api);
    setSocket(newSocket);
    const username = localStorage.getItem('username');
    setMyusername(username);

    newSocket.on('message', handleReceivedMessage);
    newSocket.on('privateMessage', handleReceivedMessagePrivate);
    newSocket.on('connect', () => {
      setUserId(newSocket.id);
      newSocket.emit('setUsername', username);
    });
    if(!initialDataFetched) {
      fetchChatData(username);
      setinitialDataFetched(true);
    }
    
  }, [api]);


app.js
function App() {
  const api = "http://localhost:8080";
  const [store, setStore] = useState();
  const [showSearchResult, setShowSearchResult] = useState(false);

  const updateStore = (data) => {
    setStore(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className='mainApp'>
      <ChatContext.Provider value={{ api, store, updateStore, showSearchResult, setShowSearchResult }}>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Login />} /> 
            <Route path="/mainpanel" element={<MainPanel />} />
            <Route path="/rooms/" element={<Room />} />

          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </ChatContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}


Now the issue is when I run all the socket servers. They all are getting connected with unknown and printing socket.id continuously and randomly(which should not occur) and communication does not occurs.
There are so much print but in real there are only two users user1 and user2.
server1
New user connected -> TgTAgdIkxgvbQS15AAAE  on PORT --> username 4001
New user connected -> Kt3Z_EXytt6sUDH5AAAK  on PORT --> username 4001
New user connected -> oK2zync3xT1b4FBUAAAP  on PORT --> username 4001
New user connected -> 07gSFZLnADv__ZisAAAS  on PORT --> username 4001
New user connected -> tbvoim0zUfHXnEVKAAAT  on PORT --> username 4001

server2
New user connected -> RawBlM_7Y1JMhp_bAADn  on PORT --> 4002
New user connected -> ZRF6Nr-qClCD3K9dAADq  on PORT --> 4002
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> A_tb4NRJGXzvoXwfAADv  on PORT --> 4002
User disconnected
New user connected -> Ycrh4CVvLYfgt96vAADx  on PORT --> 4002
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> NOJoJDFoF8Ucz5OIAAD2  on PORT --> 4002
User disconnected
New user connected -> 3S55_55A_gWWP9NOAAD5  on PORT --> 4002
User disconnected
New user connected -> J6efH-fepC_4aPomAAD9  on PORT --> 4002

server3
New user connected -> wImmJwBfE8wo8MhYAAEG  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> P0vuOGdXyKOtmzqhAAEJ  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
New user connected -> njDaGQHzJywH1upJAAEL  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> X1Fgn8AqWmmf_o1uAAEO  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> XTi4s6MJytczkl1UAAEQ  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> vgu57U3p41NLQY9_AAES  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> zJPY00O_apWAyal2AAEU  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> dUJhUM8kjpzdwJeXAAEX  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
New user connected -> h9DkdxDig5XvpbSQAAEa  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
New user connected -> uLeIIK-TlvW3MQGMAAEc  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> 5S-6dWw39qloC1IDAAEe  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> kdxEWfpoFSlIfcKZAAEg  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
New user connected -> CWPD1w0ZseFZT7X3AAEj  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> 4FoufpwSEXq3eWdAAAEm  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
New user connected -> r9HGMlQ4yGcRF8zoAAEo  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> wgHM9oW9izwaeqr4AAEr  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> AonCTiG1uPu9gEWHAAEw  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> 3TuAwdtPWmTMx4trAAEy  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> Z3kcBVKFRF6EmJhUAAE0  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> _USV1n1W9aCOoEBQAAE2  on PORT --> 4003
New user connected -> tuxnwDYVKQE5-b2TAAE5  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> UELLulq0iWlVHURKAAE9  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> tb3FGcqJGj2Eh51gAAFA  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> xhf5_9zZqpXrOH6MAAFC  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> n8X4SpZ0Dt7QXM94AAFH  on PORT --> 4003
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
User disconnected
New user connected -> FaRf7nRUlyR-dM6kAAFa  on PORT --> 4003

and if we talk about how actual and correct console looks like without nginx is
New user connected -> 07gSFZLnADv__ZisAAAS  on PORT --> user2 4001
New user connected -> tbvoim0zUfHXnEVKAAAT  on PORT --> user1 4001
Username set for tbvoim0zUfHXnEVKAAAT: user1
Username set for 07gSFZLnADv__ZisAAAS: user2

Which is working when I am not using Nginx.
I want when a user connects then send the user to server1:4001 and when another user connects send him to server2:4002 and so on in round robin fashion.
I considered the solution from Socket.io not working with nginx which did not worked for me. But I think the problem is approximately similar.

Once that connection is established between a client and a particular socket.io server instance, it needs to stay connected to that same instance throughout its whole session.
Thus, you need to configure sticky sessions on Nginx in order for this to work.
You can achieve this by using the IP Hash:
http {
    upstream socket_services {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:4001;
        server localhost:4002;
        server localhost:4003;
    }
}


Its sending requests on only PORT 4002 Here is my code https://github.com/cosmos-dx/Scalable-Chat-Application-Using-Kafka
